# Windows 7 Backup - Only backing up one drive on a backup that normally backs up two drives?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

I use two HDDs (one internal to my laptop, and one external) that I normally backup on to a third backup hard drive.

Is it possible to do a backup of just one of the non-backup-drives so that it doesn't take as long to back up?

If so, will I be able to re-include the external hdd? In the next backup?

Comment: What kind of backup? Is it a Delta backup, or just a regular image?

Comment: Complete PC Backup.

Answer (score 0):

The W7 backup automatically selects the OS partition and cannot be de-selected.

This is why I use Acronis, back up any partition or disk you wish.
http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the freeware [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) and highly recommend it.